# Definition of tf.Variables (using a list?)

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I am starting with Tensorflow and so far I have only dealt with 'shallow' feed-forward networks or neural networks with a small number of hidden layers, whose corresponding W's were defined individually in a way such as this (the example corresponds to the initialization of a network with five hidden layers):

```
  W1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([784,200], mean=0.0, stddev=0.1))
  W2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([200,100], mean=0.0, stddev=0.1))
  W3 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([100,60], mean=0.0, stddev=0.1))
  W4 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([60,30], mean=0.0, stddev=0.1))
  W5 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([30,10], mean=0.0, stddev=0.1))
  b1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([200]))
  b2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([100]))
  b3 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([60]))
  b4 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([30]))
  b5 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([10]))
```

My question is whether there exists any mechanism to pass the depth of the NN as a hyperparameter (while specifying the number of nodes per layer), so that you could avoid this step, in case you are dealing with deeper networks.

Many thanks in advance, and may you have a nice weekend.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a single function that takes a list of layer size and outputs a feed forward network, but it would be a relatively straight forward function to write if you use the Keras API included in Tensorflow,

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/basic_classification

You could write a function that takes a list of layer sizes, and non-linearities (relu, sigmoid, ...) and outputs a feed forward network using the [`keras.Sequential`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models/Sequential) class.  Keras is a great high level API for creating neural networks and is already included in Tensorflow.  In addition Tensorflow is committed to making it even more central in v2.0 ( https://medium.com/tensorflow/standardizing-on-keras-guidance-on-high-level-apis-in-tensorflow-2-0-bad2b04c819a)